# Google maps link with label

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to create a Google maps link by building it up with long and lat provided from the database. The link I get from the PHP echo is `http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&t=m&q=loc:59.337129+18.032856`

Is there a way to point to the same spot on the map but get a friendlier label, like in this case something like Stockholm, Sweden.

Comment: Do you mean you want Stockholm to be shown on the Gmaps page instead of loc... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&t=m&q=59.337129,18.032856+(Some label)](http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&t=m&q=59.337129,18.032856%20%28Some%20label%29)

See for details:
http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Comment: This no longer works in 2016 and the link is broken. Any suggestions please?